# Automatically push / nest object within a parent object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am currently working on an excel like behaviour for some task. 
All "tr"s are bound to the variable $test

```
var $test = $('tbody tr');
```

Now I use the jQuery .each function to run throuhg all trs and collect its relevant contents like this :

```
$test.each(function(index, element){
    var $row_id = $(this).data("rowid");
    var status = $(this).find('#status option:selected').val();
    var ma_name = $(this).find('#ma-name').val();
    var datum = $(this).find('#datum').val();
    var firmenname1 = $(this).find('#firmenname1').val();
    var firmenname2 = $(this).find('#firmenname2').val();
    var limit = $(this).find('#limit').val();
    var gruppe_kredit = $(this).find('#gruppe_kredit').val();

    var omv_kdnr = $(this).find('#omv_kdnr').val();

    var sap_kdnr = $(this).find('#sap_kdnr').val();

    var fos = $(this).find('#fos').val();

    var hga_kdnr = $(this).find('#fos').val();

    var pushObj = {row_id: $row_id,....};
});
```

Since the pushObject gets greated and stuffed with content each time the each function gets executed I need a way to "push" this object into a parent object which I can later use with AJAX.

The behaviour I'd wish for would be like this:

```
var parentObj = {};

$.each(function(){
// in each run the newly created object gets nested into the parentObject which results in the parent object having X-childObjects
});
```

So after, lets say 5 each runs, the parentObj should contain : [0],[1],...,[4] objects.

Could anyone guide me throuhg that process ?

Comment: What do you mean with "guide me through the process?", saying what do you need exactly would help more.   If you want to symply add a object to parentObj it needs to be an array , so you can simply do parentObj.push(myObject) because the array has push property, not objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution by storing pushObj inside array variable like so :

```
// add here
var parentObj = [];
$test.each(function (index, element) {
    var $row_id = $(this).data("rowid");
    var status = $(this).find('#status option:selected').val();
    var ma_name = $(this).find('#ma-name').val();
    var datum = $(this).find('#datum').val();
    var firmenname1 = $(this).find('#firmenname1').val();
    var firmenname2 = $(this).find('#firmenname2').val();
    var limit = $(this).find('#limit').val();
    var gruppe_kredit = $(this).find('#gruppe_kredit').val();

    var omv_kdnr = $(this).find('#omv_kdnr').val();

    var sap_kdnr = $(this).find('#sap_kdnr').val();

    var fos = $(this).find('#fos').val();

    var hga_kdnr = $(this).find('#fos').val();


    var pushObj = {
        row_id: $row_id,
        ....
    };

   // add here
   parentObj.push(pushObj);

});

// later on here access parentObj variable
```

Comment: Okay - so that solution would result in an Array having multiple objects as indexes ? Like array[0] == first object and so on?

Comment: Yes, try it out. Supposed to be the ouput like this : `[{ row_id : val1,..},{ row_id : val2,..},{ row_id : val3,..}]` and access it something like this `parentObj[0].row_id`